# VB.NET: Declaring a function inside a base class non-overridable

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

I have a base class `foo` that will be used in multiple child classes of similar but slightly different function:

```
Public MustInherit Class foo
    Public Function bar1() as Something
        ''// Perfectly OK to change what this method does
    End Function

    Public Function bar2() as Something
        ''// Does a very specific thing I don't want changed ever,
        ''// but this function must be inherited
    End Function
End Class
```

How do I get the compiler to generate an error when `bar2()` is overridden by a child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the [NotOverridable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta771xh0(v=VS.71).aspx?ppud=4) keyword in the function definition:

```
Public NotOverridable Function bar2() As Something
    ''// Does a very specific thing I don't want changed ever,
    ''// but this function must be inherited
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[NotOverridable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta771xh0%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) ?

Comment: *(smacking forehead)*  Google turned up nothing for me.  Thank you!